# What is the difference between Swift 2.0 do-try-catch and regular Java/C#/C++ exceptions

Tags: swift, error-handling, runtime-error, swift2

It seems that Swift 2.0 has changed from traditional ObjC (NSError returning) and Swift 1.X (Success/Failure optionals) conventions of runtime error handling, to something that looks very similar to exception handling in languages like Java/C#/C++/etc.

Apple has traditionally [emphasized use of `NSError` instead of throwing `NSException for runtime errors`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) (vs programmer errors), as `NSException` stack unwinding could cause memory leaks with default ObjC compiler settings.

Now they have however devised something that looks very, very similar to traditional exceptions. My question is:

Are there any real differences between Swift 2.0 error handling and traditional exception handling beside *nomenclature* (error vs exception) and *syntax* (do-catch, instead of try-catch, try used before method call, etc).

Comment: Apple mentions (in Using Swift with Cocoa and ObjC) that Swift `do-catch` statements do work with NSError returning methods automatically (using some code conventions), but do not catch NSExceptions thrown by ObjC code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 3 major differences I have found:

1. It is not necessary to list all errors a function can throw, only a `throws` keyword is needed.
2. There is no significant slowdown when using these errors, while Java and other languages need to construct an `Exception` object and unwind the stack. In Swift a `throws` keyword can be viewed as the function returning an `Either`-object, with one being the original return type, and the other being an `ErrorType` value.
3. In Swift all errors need to be handled or declared to be thrown, it is impossible to get an error from a method that does not state it is throwing an error. (in Java terms, all errors are "checked exceptions")

Comment: I don't know about Java, but in Swift you can also do _easily_  do either of the three: a. ignore the error `try?` b. crash upon the error `try!` c. handle the error `do-try-catch`. I mentioned this because I'm not sure if you can do all in Java or if it's as easy as Swift, but likely you can