# Handling conditions caused by programmer's errors in Swift

Tags: swift, exception

Swift offers exception-handling capabilities that are useful in situations when errors are out of programmer's control (missing files, dropped connections, et cetera). Although I could use the same mechanism for reporting situations caused by programmer's errors (index out of bounds, range errors, et cetera) I am wondering if that is the intended way of using exceptions.

In Objective-C code a common way to deal with these situations was through asserts. On the other hand, using exceptions was somewhat discouraged in Objective-C, so there may be no one-for-one substitution here.

Similarly, in Java there are checked and unchecked exceptions, with the intention to use unchecked ones for programmer's mistakes.

My understanding is that there is no checked/unchecked distinction among exceptions in Swift. I would like to find out if using exceptions or asserts is the proper way of reporting programmer's mistakes in Swift, or if I should use some other mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its similar syntax to Java's exception handling, Swift's `do/catch` is for handling errors.  In other words, Swift does not support exception handling.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740997/what-is-the-difference-between-swift-2-0-do-try-catch-and-regular-java-c-c-ex) for some differences between Java's exception handling and Swift's error handling.  An additional item to add to the answer there is that Swift's error handling doesn't provide any stack unwinding.

`do/catch` is for handling recoverable errors; `assert` and `precondition` are for handling unrecoverable programmer errors.

[See here](http://ericasadun.com/2015/12/15/interesting-discussions-on-swift-evolution/) for a discussion and a quote from [Dave Abrahams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abrahams_(computer_programmer)) on when to use `assert` vs `precondition`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the short answer is "use preconditions".

Comment: It depends.  If you're trying to identify and remove programmer errors during your building process, then use `assert`, which will help you to identify when conditions are not met in debug builds.  If, for example, you are writing a framework, and you want to guard against unrecoverable violations of some condition in release builds, then use `precondition`.