# Can I restrict the type that a function throws in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

When calling a function in Swift 3 that `throws`, you have to be exhaustive in catching all possible errors, which often means you have an unnecessary extra `catch {}` at the end to handle errors that won't happen.

Is it possible to say `throws MyErrorType` so that the compiler can know you have indeed been exhaustive when you handle all cases from that enumeration?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740997/what-is-the-difference-between-swift-2-0-do-try-catch-and-regular-java-c-c-ex.

Answer (score 7):

There's no simple way to be type-safe with thrown errors.  Consider this, if the compiler allowed you to specify `throws MyErrorType`, then it would also have to ensure within that function body that you're not `try`ing a function that could potentially throw a different type outside of a do/catch block. (Well there is but it would add layers of unnecessary complexity).  The Swift compiler can already be slow and get stuck in loops when inferring types, inferring Thrown types all the way up a chain of throwing functions could be a nightmare.

The running idea is that for most errors you're going to handle them in a small subset of ways anyhow.

That being said, there's no need for you to add extra `catch let error as MyErrorType` clauses, you can simply use a switch in a catch block like so:

```
do {
  try something()
} catch let e {
  switch e {
  case let m as MyErrorType: handleMyError(m)
  case let o as OtherErrorType: handleOther(o)
  case is ThirdErrorType: print("error \(e)")
  default: handleElse(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: How did Java solve this problem without running into the problems that you mention the Swift compiler would run into? I've never heard that the implementation of _checked exceptions_ in Java being either slow or complex.

Comment: @Feuermurmel Because Java will just allow an exception that isn't explicitly caught by type to be raised to the JVM.  Swift will not, it is fully type-safe even for thrown errors, therefor if a function is to specify the type it throws, then any calling function must then ensure it catches errors that aren't of the type the caller can throw.  Not only would this type checking get exponentially more complex on bigger projects, it would pretty much totally defeat the purpose of letting throwing functions call other throwing functions outside of do/catch blocks (you'd always have to use them)

Comment: What you're writing is nonsense. You say that type checking with typed errors gets _exponentially more complex_, without backing it up. Again, `javac` does this without this performance/complexity issue. You are mixing up Java, the language, (specified by the _The Java® Language Specification_) and the JVM, (specified by the _The Java® Virtual Machine Specification_) saying that the latter does not type-check checked exceptions does not mean that the former doesn't fully do so.

Comment: Also, there is now a `Result` type in Swift, which is equivalent to checked exceptions in their expressiveness. Solving the problem of type-checking code that uses `Result` is equivalent to solving the problem for typed errors, so the Swift compiler is obviously capable of doing that without the complexity issues that you mention. It can be done without global analysis. Also, a lot of other languages have similar Result types (e.g. Rust or Haskell) and they were also able to solve the complexity problems.

Comment: Good summary of why the Swift team decided against typed errors. Compiler performance or complexity is not mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722962/402281

Comment: You seem to not understand what Result is, or know that it's basically been made entirely obsolete with structured concurrency.  Result errors are not thrown errors, they're strongly typed because they had to be (due to old generic constraints), but they still require some level of type checking in a do/catch block like my above answer to ensure the right error type is thrown or something is converted to that error type.  That's more reasonable because it puts the type checking into swift's normal type checking system, instead of trying to do type checking up several trees of call chains.

Comment: Compiler performance doesn't need to be mentioned in that answer, it's assumed when you know what he's talking about... buried in this sentence "[...] I have a choice: I bury it somehow in the existing 3, or I force every caller to rewrite their error handling code to deal with it.".  The complexity of every function checking that it handles every error type possible in the call tree grows exponentially with project size, and the fact that it would require an entire Foundation rewrite (which they've done anyway but) also hints at it.

Comment: Again, Java handles this by having javac check exception types, BUT, it doesn't actually do so super strictly.  If an exception type is actually NOT handled by a function in java, it bubbles all the way up to the JVM.  The compile time checks exist to see if "this exception cld possibly be thrown" at compile time, but it doesnt prevent runtime exceptions of different types from being thrown.  This is simply not possible in Swift due to language design, we don't allow any unhandled errors to escape a function, period.  That's the benefit of much stricter type checking in Swift compared to Java.

Comment: How is the statement "I bury it somehow in the existing 3, or I force every caller to rewrite their error handling code to deal with it" is related to compiler performance?  IIUC, this statement is about a programmer, that has forces an API-incompatible change on users of a function.

Comment: I'm not saying that there are no other reasons for `Result` to have a typed error. I'm just saying that it proves that the compiler is able to handle typed errors.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion for this problem is instead of throwing an error return a `Result` type in your function. It would be something like this.

```swift
enum MyCustomError: Error {
    case genericError
}

func operationThatFails() -> Result<Response, MyCustomError> {
    guard requiredConsition() else {
        return .failure(.genericError)
    }
    return Response()
}
```

Then you can handle the error like this:

```swift
let result = operationThatFails()
switch result {
case .success(let value):
    // handle success
case .failure(let error):
    // handle error
}
```

This way your error is always type safe